# force ie11 to re-render the page after downloading fonts

Tags: rendering, font-face, internet-explorer-11

I have yet another curious problem with the internet explorer 11.

My application has an embedded font (woff only) used in a button with rounded corners.

When the page first loads in IE11 the button is too small for the text inside. After reloading the page or hover the button it resizes the button correctly.

Now my theory is that IE loads the page and renders it and then loads the font without rendering the page again.

Is there a standard approach to such problems?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I am loading content but it is hidden awaiting a user interaction. After the user interaction the content appears, but the fonts do not render as icons.